# Is there a way to embed a logstash in java

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, groovy, logstash

There is a test in an application I'm on that embeds an Elasticsearch instance (based on a .zip file) and uses it to tst if a class writes correctly to that Elasticsearch like this :

```
 embeddedElastic = EmbeddedElastic.builder()
            .withElasticVersion("5.5.2")
            .withInResourceLocation("./libs/elasticsearch-5.5.2.zip")
            .withStartTimeout(300L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .withSetting(PopularProperties.HTTP_PORT, elasticPort)
            .build()
```

It's using this library : https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch

Is there an equivalent of this library for logstash ?

Thanks

Comment: Recommendations for libraries are off-topic for stack overflow, sorry. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'd look into test containers if you need to steer this from your code (e.g. testing). Otherwise use docker directly to fire things up.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute logstash as command line from a Java program